# Pandas compute all combinations between two columns just once

Tags: python, pandas

**Disclaimer this is a simplified example, in the real case I need to compute a heavy cost function avoiding repetition a + b == b + a counts as duplicated**

I have a dataframe with a string column, in this example I simply add them up:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'people':['foo','bar','baz','qux']})
```

For every name, I add any other name in the dataframe:

```
results = []
for _,r in data.iterrows():
    all_people = data['people'].tolist()
    person = r['people']
    results.append({'combination':[person+n for n in all_people]})
```

After some manipulation:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(results)
d.explode('combination')
```

I obtain

```
|    | combination   |
|---:|:--------------|
|  0 | foofoo        |
|  0 | foobar        |
|  0 | foobaz        |
|  0 | fooqux        |
|  1 | barfoo        |
|  1 | barbar        |
|  1 | barbaz        |
|  1 | barqux        |
|  2 | bazfoo        |
|  2 | bazbar        |
|  2 | bazbaz        |
|  2 | bazqux        |
|  3 | quxfoo        |
|  3 | quxbar        |
|  3 | quxbaz        |
|  3 | quxqux        |
```

For my logic foo+bar is the same as far+boo and with a very large dataframe that is a problem so ideally if I would like that once I have computed all combinations using foo to remove it from all_people but feels ugly, is there a more pythonic way

Comment: `combos = list(itertools.combinations(df['col1'],df['col2']))`  ... I think

Comment: So does the expected output include foobaz and bazfoo? What is the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
array = data.to_numpy()
rows, columns = np.triu_indices(len(array))
res = pd.DataFrame(array[rows] + array[columns], columns=["combination"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  combination
0      foofoo
1      foobar
2      foobaz
3      fooqux
4      barbar
5      barbaz
6      barqux
7      bazbaz
8      bazqux
9      quxqux
```

The above solution sums every pair only once and everything is done at numpy level, although the elements are strings.

Comment: Nice solution, but not sure in practice with many records, e.g. 1mm x 1mm you will fit this array in RAM, which is why you might needs some kind of python generator

Comment: Nice catch @Attack68 updated the answer with a solution that only stores the original array

Answer (score 0):

A more Pythonic method is using the `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` generator:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
d = pd.DataFrame({ 'combinations': [ ''.join(c) for c in \
                    combinations_with_replacement(data['people'], 2) ] })
print(d)
```

Output:

```
  combinations
0       foofoo
1       foobar
2       foobaz
3       fooqux
4       barbar
5       barbaz
6       barqux
7       bazbaz
8       bazqux
9       quxqux
```

You can also compute the `all_people` list only once outside the loop, and when you loop over it inside you can start at the index of the row you are at, to avoid repetition:

```
all_people = data['people'].tolist()

results = []
for i, r in data.iterrows():
    person = r['people']
    results.append({'combination':[person+n for n in all_people[i:]]})

d = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(d.explode('combination'))
```

Output:

```
  combination
0      foofoo
0      foobar
0      foobaz
0      fooqux
1      barbar
1      barbaz
1      barqux
2      bazbaz
2      bazqux
3      quxqux
```

Comment: The output of the OP includes foobaz and bazfoo and other repetitions as well

Comment: Is this scalable thought with let's say 1000000 records?

Comment: @DaniMesejo The output in the question is the undesired output, from how I understood the question at least.

Comment: 1,000,000 unique records produces (1mm choose 2 =) 500 billion combinations.